# php replace a value by another with a listing properly

Tags: php

Hello i have a php file that generate a .dat file and i want to replace a specific value, (transform a reference to another), before generate the .dat file, with the help of a listing.

I have try test coding to replace a value "a" to a value "b" but i don't know witch is the best way and how to implement it in my php file witch generate the .dat.

```
$cart_contents[$i] = $product['cart_quantity'].'x'.$product['reference'];
```

In this line i want to replace the part below by another with my listing

```
.$product['reference']
```

Here is the test i try to replace files

```
<?php
$product = array(
"202"    => "MY REMPLACEMENT",
"203"    => "MY ANOTHER REMPLACEMENT",
);
echo    $product['202'];

//or 
$product['105'] = "MY REMPLACEMENT";
$product['106'] = "MY ANOTHER REMPLACEMENT";
echo    $product['106'];
?>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: i don't know how to modify .$product['reference'] to replace it by another value with a listing

Comment: `$product['reference'] = 'my new value';`

Comment: Well it's a bit more complex $product['reference'] display a number link to my product for exemple 202, i want to replace this number by a name i choose in a listing like the listing i put on top of the post. For ememple if $product['reference'] is "202" it become "MY REMPLACEMENT", if $product['reference'] is "203" it become "MY ANOTHER REMPLACEMENT" and so on.

Comment: So the value of `$product['reference']` is the index of `$product`?

Comment: $product['reference'] display a number witch is set in the back office in a product edit page. I can change the code to $product['name'] witch gona display the name of the product. But i only want to use the $product['reference'] number and transform every different numbers to a specific text (an abbreviation of each product).(The all point of this, is to have the right abbreviation of the product that we print on a label for the deliveries).